# Add a javascript array to Asp.Net MVC form's submit (replacing model List)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Let's imagine I have the following situation:

I have a question form and I want to add answer choices to it (my user should be allowed to add as many choices as he wants).

So I have this ViewModel (being sent to the view).

```
public class QuestionEdit
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string Question { get; set; }

    public List<Choice> Choices { get; set; }
}

public class Choice
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string Choice { get; set; }

    public bool Correct {get; set;^}
}
```

My Controller's Edit Post looks like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Question,Choices")] QuestionEdit vm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            /*Removed for clarity*/
        }

        return View(vm)
    }
```

Is there any way of me getting the content from `Choices` and converting it to a javascript list, changing it as my user adds or removes items only by using javascript/ajax and when submitting the form, would it be a way for me to adding it back as if it were the `Choices` that my controller will be able to read?

I am aware that I could use the an custom EditorFor for this List, but everytime someone adds a new Choice I would have to post the entire form to add it and them get it back, so I wanted to change this only through javascript, as it requires only simple validations (not needing any server/database validation).

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, but you have not posted your view or the scripts so hard to give you an answer.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) may help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use as much JavaScript and ajax as you need, as long as in your form you have inputs that are named in a way that the model binder expects.

What I mean by that is, you can create form inputs with a name attribute in the form of:

```
<input type="text" name="Choices[0].Id" />
<input type="text" name="Choices[0].Choice" />
<input type="hidden" name="Choices[0].Correct" />
<input type="text" name="Choices[1].Id" />
<input type="text" name="Choices[1].Choice" />
<input type="hidden" name="Choices[1].Correct" />
```

And so on. When you post your form, the model binder will attempt to take whatever values are attached and set them on your `QuestionEdit` object based on the name. So in the above case, `vm.Choices` in your action method will contain 2 items.

This link gives some pretty good examples that should point you in the right direction:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/551576/ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding-and-Data-Annotation

From there, it's up to your JavaScript to create input elements accordingly and append them to your form.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've struggled a bit to generate all the inputs with the proper naming, but the View persisted the information to the Controller.